# Geotiff image plotting in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, gdal, geotiff, rasterio

I am new geotif image ploting in python. I have two Geotiff images of the same region. However, after plotting these two images they are not matching. The below is the meta information for both the images.

#### Image 1

[image]

```
Files: sli_hh_ML_I_221.tif
Size is 640, 7368
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            ELLIPSOID["unknown",1737400,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Reference meridian",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Polar Stereographic (variant A)",
        METHOD["Polar Stereographic (variant A)",
            ID["EPSG",9810]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",90,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",south,
            MERIDIAN[90,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                    ID["EPSG",9122]]],
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",south,
            MERIDIAN[180,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                    ID["EPSG",9122]]],
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-56469.605829227773938,5384.527309082705870)
Pixel Size = (89.627161160045119,-21.283702822737492)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -56469.606,    5384.527) ( 95d26'48.61"W, 88d 7'46.10"N)
Lower Left  (  -56469.606, -151433.795) ( 20d27' 1.68"W, 84d40'26.23"N)
Upper Right (     891.777,    5384.527) (170d35'46.03"E, 89d49'12.04"N)
Lower Right (     891.777, -151433.795) (  0d20'14.66"E, 85d 0'32.78"N)
Center      (  -27788.914,  -73024.634) ( 20d50' 2.06"W, 87d25'25.54"N)
Band 1 Block=640x3 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
```

#### Image 2

[image]

```
*ch2_sar_ncxl_20191017t234531221_d_sli_xx_fp_hh_d18_wrp.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ch2_sar_ncxl_20191017t234531221_d_sli_xx_fp_hh_d18_wrp.tif
Size is 2294, 6273
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            ELLIPSOID["unknown",1737400,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Reference meridian",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Polar Stereographic (variant A)",
        METHOD["Polar Stereographic (variant A)",
            ID["EPSG",9810]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",90,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",south,
            MERIDIAN[90,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                    ID["EPSG",9122]]],
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",south,
            MERIDIAN[180,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                    ID["EPSG",9122]]],
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-56469.605829227773938,5384.527309082705870)
Pixel Size = (25.000000000000000,-25.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -56469.606,    5384.527) ( 95d26'48.61"W, 88d 7'46.10"N)
Lower Left  (  -56469.606, -151440.473) ( 20d26'58.70"W, 84d40'25.49"N)
Upper Right (     880.394,    5384.527) (170d42'50.59"E, 89d49'12.26"N)
Lower Right (     880.394, -151440.473) (  0d19'59.10"E, 85d 0'32.00"N)
Center      (  -27794.606,  -73027.973) ( 20d50'12.96"W, 87d25'24.93"N)
Band 1 Block=2294x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
Band 2 Block=2294x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=nan*
```

I tried with several methods but am unable to find why these two images do not display same.

Comment: What's the question, exactly? The images are different views and they are different sizes and have different pixel sizes... how are you expecting them to look? How did you plot them?

Comment: Both images have same corner latitude and longitude. But still they are not same after display.

Comment: You don't show how you display them at all, that makes it impossible to answer. In Matplotlib you for example would need to provide the correct extent, because the pixel-coordinates of both images are clearly different, they won't magically align when treated as plain assays.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using the below code for both the images in python        
`import rasterio

from matplotlib import pyplot

src = rasterio.open("Input.tif")

pyplot.imshow(src.read(1), cmap='pink')


pyplot.show()`

Comment: Try adding the correct extent to `imshow`, it's the corner coordinates as shown by `gdalinfo`. The order is `extent=(left, right, bottom, top)`, see:  
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755432/rutger-kassies, I am still unable to get the orienttation.